# Existence of joint distribution from trivariate distribution

Tags: real-analysis, probability, functional-analysis, probability-theory, probability-distributions

Let $X_1, ..., X_n$ be $n$ random variables supported on $[0, 1]$. Let $f : [0,1]^3 \to \Re_{\geq 0}$ be a trivariate symmetric pdf function supported on $[0,1]^3$.

Question: What are some sufficient conditions on $f$ to guarantee that there **exists** a joint pdf (not necessarily unique) $f^\ast(x_1, ..., x_n)$ with trivariate marginal pdf $f$ for any $(X_i, X_j, X_k), i\neq j\neq k$?